# google spreadsheets: IF and AND (cell ranges)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]I want to express:

IF a1:a5 contains the value "George" AND b1:b5 contains the value "Nick" then SUM the values of c1:c5. It seems I can't find a way to do it.

Check screenshot. All work ok if I reference ONLY one cell. What I want to say is "look in the range A1:A5 and B1:B5".

Comment: Can you have different names on ranges A and B? Or are they limited to George on `A1:A5` and Nick on `B1:B5`?

Comment: I will clarify more: I have cells A1 to A5. All contain unique values (A1=Jim, A2=Helen, A3=George, A4=....). The same with B column (B1=Nick, B2=Adam, B3=....). And finally, I have C column that contains integers (C1=10, C2=20, C3=34, ...). Now, IF A1:A5 contains a "George" AND IF B1:B5 contains a "Nick", I want the SUM of C1:C5...

Comment: It is probably easier to create a custom function through apps script, using a loop to scan every cell in `A1:B5` range.

Answer (score 2):

```
=sumproduct(A1:A5="George"; B1:B5="Nick"; C1:C5 )
```

Edit after clarification

```
=iferror(if(match("George"; A1:A5; 0)*match("Nick"; B1:B5;0); sum(C1:C5)))
```

Comment: This solution won't solve the problem I desribed unfortunately.  My query is: if value a is anywhere within range A and if value b is anywhere within range b, sum all values found in range c.

Comment: How to determine form which row in C the values should be summed? Based on the match in Col A, Col B ?  Let's say 'George' is in A10 and 'Nick' is in B20 ? What values in C should then be summed?

Comment: Or maybe you want to sum the values in C if 'George' is in Col A OR 'Nick' is in Col B ?

Comment: As I said, I would like C1 to C5 cells to be SUMed, IF within the range A1 to A5 there is a "George" string somewhere, and IF within the range B1 to B5 there is a "Nick" somewhere. I can write the formula if I check unique cells, as I wrote in my original post. Things break once I state ranges.

Comment: Added a screenshot in the original post

Comment: @ToucHDowN: edited answer.

Comment: Returns a blank cell

Comment: Can you share the spreadsheet you used to create the screenshot ?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FILTER(C1:C5; (A1:A5="George") + (B1:B5="Nick")))
```

or just:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C1:C5; (A1:A5="George") + (B1:B5="Nick")))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(JOIN(" "; A1:A5); "George")*
    REGEXMATCH(JOIN(" "; B1:B5); "Nick"); SUM(C1:C5); )
```

[image]

Comment: I'm afraid this not was I was looking for. This formula only works if values from two columns are found in the same row. Also, even so, I don't get a sum of a range, but just the value of that exact row. My query is: if value a is anywhere within range A and if value b is anywhere within range b, sum all values found in range c.

Comment: @ToucHDowN can you share a copy/sample of your sheet?

Comment: yes, please check my initial post, just added a screenshot with a formula that works, the problem arises when I want to reference ranges instead of unique cells.

Comment: I get #N/A ("No matches are found in FILTER evaluation.")

Comment: its is wrong, the SUM(C1:C5) should be 150... I don't understand why you're filtering

Comment: seems cleaner but I still get a parse error (am pretty sure I copied it ok)...

Comment: @ToucHDowN answer updated. try now

Answer (score 0):

OK, with a better understanding of what you need, you could use a script for that.

```
function onEdit(){ //every time any cell is updated, runs the function ifNick() 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var cell = sheet.getActiveCell();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() == "Sheet_Name"){
    ifNick();
  }
}

function ifNick(){ 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var george = "George";
  var nick = "Nick";
  var check = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){ //scans every non-blank data in column A 
    if(data[i][0] == george){ //[0] because column A
      check++;
    }
  }
  Logger.log(check);
  for(var j = 0; j<data.length; j++){ //scans every non-blank data in column B 
    if(data[j][1] == nick){ //[1] because column B
      check++;
    }   
  }  
  if (check > 2){
    sheet.getRange('D1').activate();
    sheet.getActiveCell().setValue("ERROR!");      
  }
  if (check == 2){
    sheet.getRange('D1').activate();
    sheet.getActiveCell().setFormula("=SUM(C1:C5)");
  } 
  else{
    sheet.getRange('D1').activate();
    sheet.getActiveCell().setValue("Your condition was not met!");
  }
};
```

---

Here is one without Nick, George, and with both:

[image: No Nick]
[image: No George]
[image: Both]

---

Should you enter more than one of each, it will also give you an error, but you can edit it if needed.